# How to publish real time messages on GCP pubsub topic from on premise NiFi workflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-nifi, google-cloud-pubsub

**Context:**

I have multiple applications on premise which are publishing real-time messages on Enterprise Kafka and Solace queues. Volume and velocity of the messages are considerable. These messages are consumed by message processing modules and store that into real time data-store hosted on premise as of now. we are planning to move the message processing modules and real-time data-store on GCP.

**Problem statement:**

As the message processing modules and real-time data-store are being moved to GCP there is a need to publish / push the messages from "the *on premise Kafka topics and Solace queues* to *GCP Pubsub topics*".

For this I was planning to write a NiFi workflow on the on premise NiFi cluster.
It would be great if somebody share thoughts if has already done similar attempt?

Answer (score 1):

I've worked briefly with both Kafka and GCP PubSub. I haven't worked much with Solace but from what I know, you may have to do a bit of code change on the `nifi-hms-bundle` to customize the JMS controller service to have standard JMS JNDI connection factory, after which you can leverage NiFi's `ConsumeJMS` and `PublishJMS` processor to read/write to/from Solace queues.

So in general, your flow would be like this:

[image]

- You have `ConsumeKafka` configured to the correct topic and `ConsumeJMS` configured to use the the custom `JNDIConnectionFactoryProvider` instead of the built-in `JMSConnectionFactoryProvider`.
- Connect the `success` output of both these processors and connect it with `PublishGCPPubSub`.

I would recommend to use record based `ConsumeKafka` processors. Choose the processor of mathcing Kafka API version.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmNHx.png) https://dev.solace.com/integration-guides/nifi/

Comment: Thanks a lot Sivaprasanna! I will try this option and let you know in case of further queries. BTW wondering if you have done any performance bench marking i.e. latency, thru-put also any challenges in setting up secure connection in PROD env. Thanks again!